# int256 range on geth command line

Tags: go-ethereum, console, integers

When I do the following on the geth command line:

```
20000000000000000000-19999999999999999989
```

it returns `0`

I'm guessing this is because of a 64 bit limit on ints.

Is there a way to get it to return `11`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 web3.toBigNumber("20000000000000000000").minus(web3.toBigNumber("19999999999999999989"))
```